# How to retain form field values in Ajax Post Request

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I am using a form with two buttons embedded the first checks for username availability and the other submits the form. Both the buttons type are set as button.

The first button ( `#btn-keywordCheck` ) which makes an AJAX post request is clearing all the form fields entered by the user after the success alert which is undesirable. The latter ( `#btn-signup` ) works as expected. Can some one please give me a fix for this?

Here is the Jquery script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#btn-keywordCheck').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/reservedKeyCheck",
            type : 'GET',
            data : "keyword="+$("#keyword").val(),
            async : false,
            cache : false,
            contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            processData : false,
            success: function(output){
            alert(output.success);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error){
           alert(error.message);
          }
    });
    });

    $('#btn-signup').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/signup",
            data: $("#signupform").serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                success: function(output){
                alert(output.success);              
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error){
               alert(error.message);
              }
    });
});

});
```

Here is the HTML code (I am using bootstrap)

```
            <form id="signupform" class="form-horizontal" method="post"
                role="form">

                <div id="signupalert" style="display: none"
                    class="alert alert-danger">
                    <p>Error:</p>
                    <span></span>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="orgname" class="col-md-4 control-label">Organization
                        Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="orgname"
                            placeholder="Full Name">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="keyword" class="col-md-4 control-label">Keyword</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keyword" id="keyword"
                            placeholder="Short code identifier">
                            <p></p>
                         <button id="btn-keywordCheck"class="btn btn-info">Check Availability</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email"
                            placeholder="Email Address">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Set
                        Password</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password"
                            placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="confirmPassword" class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm
                        Password</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control"
                            name="confirmPassword" placeholder="Retype Password">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="phone" class="col-md-4 control-label">Phone
                        Number</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone"
                            placeholder="Numbers only">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="address" class="col-md-4 control-label">Address</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="address" rows="3"
                            placeholder="Optional" id="address"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <!-- Button -->
                    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-11">
                        <button id="btn-signup" type="button" class="btn btn-info">
                            <i class="icon-hand-right"></i> &nbsp Sign Up
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: use `prevetDefault();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your button click listener and add `preventDefault();`. Your page is refreshing when you click the Check Availability button

```
$('#btn-keywordCheck').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/reservedKeyCheck",
        type : 'GET',
        data : "keyword="+$("#keyword").val(),
        async : false,
        cache : false,
        contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        processData : false,
        success: function(output){
        alert(output.success);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error){
       alert(error.message);
      }
    preventDefault();
});
```

EDIT: If this doesn't work, you might have to change your click action a bit.

```
$('#btn-keywordCheck').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/reservedKeyCheck",
        type : 'GET',
        data : "keyword="+$("#keyword").val(),
        async : false,
        cache : false,
        contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        processData : false,
        success: function(output){
            alert(output.success);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error){
            alert(error.message);
        }
    });
});
```